# How to use Coredata NSPredicate like 'left join' in sql

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

CoreDataModel:(I put JSONFORMAT HERE.)

```
Questions [{qid:1,comments:[{cid:1,user:{'uid':3}},{cid:2,user:{'uid':4}}]},
           {qid:2,comments:[{cid:1,user:{'uid':4}},{cid:2,user:{'uid':5}}]}]
```

Question has relation with comments one2many, 
comment has one2one relation with user.

How do I search the question which had been *commentd by the user (uid=1)*, 
using NSPredicate?

**below is my model pic**

[image]

Comment: You forgot the reverse relationships. Don't treat core data like a database! Core Data is neither a database, nor a wrapper around SQlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request entity should be `Question`
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:SUBQUERY(comments,$comment,$comment.user.usr_id == %@).@count != 0",userId]`

Comment: you can't use such predicate with one to many relationship comments.user.

Comment: What is SUBQUERY here?   i am trying this in swift